# Reset plot with tabPanel UI

Tags: r, shiny

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ECharts2Shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)

demo <- data.frame(c(5,0,0,1,20,25,14,1,53),
               c(1,1,1,2,12,22,5,1,25),
               c(6,0,0,3,26,38,19,2,65),
               c(0,0,0,0,5,3,0,0,6),
               c(0,1,1,0,1,6,0,0,7),
               c(6,0,1,3,32,47,19,2,78),
               c(2,0,0,1,8,13,10,1,33),
               c(0,0,0,0,0,9,2,0,4),
               c(1,0,0,1,6,4,6,0,23))

names(demo) <- c("M", "F", "O", "B", "C", "Re", "Vi", "Ac", "Co")
row.names(demo) <- c("Az","Bh", "Bi", "Ch", "Ha", "Ka", "N.G", "Ra", "Su") 


ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "reset example"),
    dashboardSidebar(tags$img(src="bar.PNG", style ="text-align:center;")),
    dashboardBody(h3("example"),
        mainPanel( shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
             tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
             tabPanel(h5("1"), infoBox("a,1,1")),
             tabPanel(h5("2"), infoBox("b,2,2")),
             tabPanel(h5("Block wise"), 
    loadEChartsLibrary(), 
    tags$div(id="demo1", 
    style="width:100%;height:500px;"), 
                      deliverChart(div_id="demo1"), 
                      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Data"),
                      actionButton("reset","reset plot")))))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
observeEvent(input$reset,{
shinyjs::runjs("location.reload();")
})

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste('data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
},
content = function(con) {
  write.csv(demo, con)
})

renderBarChart(div_id = "demo1", grid_left = '1%', direction = 
               "vertical", data = demo)})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I wanted to reset the plot after selection of features.
While hitting "**reset plot**" button, it takes to the 1st tab "**1**" in the tabPanel instead of resetting the plot to by default.

[image]

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciable.
The click on "**reset plot**" should not route to the tabPanel "**1**" and it should reset the plot as to default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your event reset to this:

`observeEvent(input$reset,{
    renderBarChart(div_id = "demo1", grid_left = '1%', direction = 
                     "vertical", data = demo)
  })`

Your code is resetting the whole shiny, you only want to reset the plot, if I understood well.
Note that your real app will require other tweaks if you did not post your real code.

Comment: Thank you Jonny for your support. But one thing you can observe i.e. the download button which is giving us a pop  up window to save the file as .csv is not working. While saving the file the option to save File Type as .csv option not active. I am not able to save it as .csv file. Can you please have a look on the functioning of Download button, please? Thank you once again.

Comment: Hi! Just write your desired name for the file with the .csv extension, i.e: "my_file.csv"

Comment: I tried but the file is getting saved in Unknown format. When I click on that saved file it asking me to open in formats available to choose one from the list. After typing a name, we need to select the 'Save as type' from the list just below the 'File Name' bar.